# GraphQL private schema returning public schema scope

Tags: craft3, graphql

I am setting up GraphQL on my Craft project, v3.3.16.3
I have a public schema exposing a public entry type, and a private schema exposing a private entry type.
When I switch between them in the GraphQL -> Explore panel, both return the results of the public schema.

See attached screens.

[image: Public schema settings]

[image: Private schema settings]

[image: Public schema query results]

[image: Private schema query results]

Any suggestions would be much appreciated! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that MAMP Pro was stripping out the Authorization header, so every request was treated as a request to the public schema. The solution for MAMP Pro was to enable "Identical PHP version for all hosts (module mode)" in the PHP tab.

Thanks to Brandon Kelly from the Craft forum for pointing me in the right direction.